# How to hide text links when viewed in mobile with bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I'd like to hide the text part of the link when viewed in mobile (xs and sm) sizes. How can I accomplish this? Does bootstrap 4 offer anything?

HTML

```
<li>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-icon"></i> Text Link</a>
</li>
```

In mobile, I should only see the `(icon)`. In desktop or tablet mode, I'll see `(icon) Text Link`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this class `hidden-sm-down` to hide on small devices

```
<li>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-icon"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Text Link</span></a>
</li>
```

You can find more about regarding this from here. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes

Comment: I appreciate you not only answering but providing a link to the classes for it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using CSS3

```css
/*Your smartphone screen width*/
@media screen and (max-width:400px){
  #myText{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-icon"></i><span id="myText">Text Link</span></a>
</li>
```